# Continuous numbering of examples (langsci-gb4e) over chapters

Tags: numbering, linguistics, gb4e, langsci-gb4e

I tried to use

```
\counterwithout{exe}{chapter}
```

for continuous numbering over chapters of langsci-gb4e examples. But the following error appears.

```
Latex Error: No counter 'exe' defined
```

Working example

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}

%\counterwithout{exe}{chapter}

\begin{document} 

    \chapter{First Chapter}

    \begin{exe}
    \ex  first example
    \end{exe}

    \chapter{Second Chapter}

    \begin{exe}
    \ex  second example
    \end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Output (I would like the second example to be numbered "(2) second example"):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a minimal example document! Are you forced to use `langsci-gb4e` as opposed to using just `gb4e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons that are completely unclear to me, `langsci-gb4e` uses the `equation` counter inside its definition of `{exe}` even though the counter used in printing the example itself is `xnumi`. On the face of it, this seems like a really bad idea, because, for example, it removes the possibility of having actual `{equation}` environments numbered independently of the `{exe}` environment, but it is what it is. So you can achieve what you want by using:

```
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
```

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}

\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document} 

    \chapter{First Chapter}

    \begin{exe}
    \ex  first example
    \end{exe}

    \chapter{Second Chapter}

    \begin{exe}
    \ex  second example
    \end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]